# AWS EC2 traffic-mirroring does not pass traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a `VPC` over `EC2` and two `Ubuntu 22.04` VMs.
I created a simple straight forward `traffic-mirroring` session, according to this [manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/what-is-traffic-mirroring.html).
But traffic does not gets replicated into destination.

- My `mirror targets` is the interface of `vm1`
- My `mirror filters` are "all protocols" source+dest CIDR `0.0.0.0/0`
- My `mirror sessions` combines both the above `mirror-target` and `mirror-filter`, and source as the interface of `vm2`

On `vm2` I use `wget` in order to produce traffic on that interface.
On `vm1` I use `tcpdump`, but I do not get any traffic mirrored from `vm2`.
I did not find any way to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
Looks like I missed that part from [Prerequisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/traffic-mirroring-getting-started.html)

> The traffic mirror target instance must allow traffic to UDP port 4789.

I had to allow `UDP` port `4789` (`vxlan`) on the targer's security groups.